# Use MvcScaffolding with Entity Framework 5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, nuget, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I would like use MvcScaffolding with EF 5 (because I use MySQL and there are not stable version of mysql connector for EF 6) but when I install MvcScaffolding with nuget, EntityFramework 6.0.2 is installed automatically

How can I use MvcScaffolding with EF 5 ? (I use VS2012)

Answer (score 0):

Since the scaffolding requires EF as a dependency it will try to install the latest version. Try adding EF5 first by using the command

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

then

```
Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

Comment: I try it but when I install MvcScaffolding it update EntityFramework with version 6